# Is my Filipino boyfriend likely to get a visitor visa for the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, filipino-citizens

After having looked at the Gov.uk website, I'm still genuinely unsure as to whether my Filipino boyfriend (who I visited in September when I flew to the Philippines), is likely to be granted a visitor visa to come and see me in the UK.

I assumed that if I acted as his financial guarantor, and sent copies of my payslip, bank account, and assets, that this would be adequate evidence that he wouldn't be claiming public funds, or doing anything else to get money. He would obviously be staying with me, so I would ensure he was fed, and take full responsibility for his welfare.

As with most Filipinos, he doesn't have any savings, and has only had jobs which are low paid-which the vast majority of Jobs in the Philippines are, by our standards. He doesn't currently have a job. Would this fact on its own, guarantee he would be refused a visa?

I really wish there was a government helpline where I could ask a real person these questions, but there isn't, and so there is nobody to ask, since automated websites don't converse.

The British Embassy in Manila was totally unhelpful when I emailed the consular section; I just got an automated email back that was basically rude, unhelpful and downright nasty. It said "We do not answer questions about visa, immigration or travel requirements." I'm glad I didn't have to turn to these obnoxious bureaucrats when I was in the Philippines! Makes me wonder what they get paid for.

So basically: would I be wasting my time and money applying for a visa for him?

Comment: A key factor examined by UK immigration is whether the applicant can afford the trip in their own right. I'd expect that someone unemployed in a low-income economy would be judged unable to afford a trip to the UK, whatever their sponsor says. Your boyfriend's chances are not good.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the information you’ve given his chances are probably quite low but it is not impossible for him to be given a visa. However, even with you acting as his sponsor he will need to show that he qualifies in his own right and, possibly most importantly, has strong ties to home that will be sufficient to convince UKVI that he will return home at the end of his visit. You will likely also need to demonstrate a relationship of a reasonable length as a reason for inviting him. Reading this [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e) may help you understand the challenges better, plus this guide https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/673351/Visit-guidance-v7.0EXT.PDF#page1